# Android - Generate shadow of the view in animation like drag drop event

Tags: android, android-animation

In my android application, I got one animation in which view is Translate from one point to another point which I can do using `TranslateAnimation` but the problem is, I need the shadow of the view left behind, just like the Drag and Drop,

I tried hack in `DragShadowBuilder` class but unsuccessful, can anyone guide me with this how to achieve this.

Thank you,